# Coming from PHP world and have some difficulties understanding this JavaScript (jQuery selection)

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

Sometimes I have difficulties with understanding JS objects. I will give a very simple example.

```
    <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>

<script>

    var myTestSelection = $('ul li').first();

    console.log(myTestSelection); //Returns object
    console.log(myTestSelection[0]); //Returns HTML WHY??????????
    console.log($(myTestSelection).eq(0));

</script>
```

When I output myTestSelection - returns object with key => 0 and value => object.

When I output myTestSelection[0] - returns `<li>Item 1</li>` WHY?

I really can't understand this behavior, and it's important for me. Can someone give a logical explanation? Thank everyone in advance for the time devoted to answer. (Sorry for the English - not mothertongue)

Comment: Hello, please update your question as it doesn't meet StackOverflow standards. Please focus on title. Here is a guide for you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is about jQuery, not native JavaScript. The phenomena you observe are the design of the jQuery API.

First, understand that jQuery selectors return array-like objects of elements matched. Thus:

```
console.log(myTestSelection);
```

...returns that array-like object. It's array-like because, as you've discovered, it's indexed, such that `[0]` will return the first matched element. Which brings me to:

```
console.log(myTestSelection[0]);
```

...returns a native reference to the first matched reference. It doesn't return HTML - it's just showing that way in your console, which tries to be helpful and demonstrate the element. It actually returns a native reference to the element.

```
typeof myTestSelection[0] == 'object'; //true - would be 'string' if it was HTML
```